# ERROR TypeError: toISOString is not a function throws when stringify used from flatted/esm

Tags: json, angular7, circular-reference

I am dealing with json circular reference object in angular7 so I used flatted package to resolve this but still not am getting following errors

ERROR TypeError: toISOString is not a function

also seeing warning like '[Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.' from flatted/esm/index.js. am using flatted 2.0.0 version.

I tried with safe-json-stringify but it throws out of memory exception and chrome got stuck.

```
import { parse, stringify } from 'flatted/esm';

 const objectTemp = {      
      'ConfigData': stringify(this.getData())     
    };
```

This.GetData() will have json circular reference object. How to stringify the json circular object.. am I missing anything here or is there any other way ?. Would be great if anyone can help me on this.?. Thanks